# cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, wcf-binding

I am using ajax enabled WCF, when i open the url in web browser i am getting this error.

> The message with Action 'http://localhost:22219/MobileService.svc/GetProductCategories' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to
>   a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender
>   and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).

MobileService code is given below

```
namespace MobileService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class MobileService
    {
        // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
        // To create an operation that returns XML,
        //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
        //     and include the following line in the operation body:
        //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
        [OperationContract]
        public void DoWork()
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            return;
        }
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetProductCategories")]
        public List<String> GetProductCategories()
        {
            List<String> categoryList = new List<string>();

            categoryList.AddRange(new String[] { "Electronics", "Housewares", "Computers", "Software", "Music" });

            return categoryList;
        }
        // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
    }
}
```

AND 
Service web.config file is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MobileService.MobileServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">

        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="MobileService.MobileService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MobileService.MobileServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MobileService.MobileService"  />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

can any one help me where i made mistake.

Comment: It's confusing because the answer was edited into the question. Originally `<webHttp />` was not there.

Comment: @DavidSherret Seconded.

Comment: I'm going to roll it back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a `<webHttp/>` endpoint behavior for your endpoint. If you add that (see below) it should work.

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MobileService.MobileServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```